# Is it allowed to protest peacefully against the government on certain issues in India?

Tags: protests, india, civil-rights

In the light of recent wave of [public protests against the government](https://www.google.co.in/#q=protest+against+delhi+gang+rape&hl=en&safe=off&tbo=u&source=univ&tbm=nws&sa=X&ei=L_vkUMOHEM3MrQf8-IC4AQ&ved=0CDEQqAI&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.bmk&fp=40d3396fbb925556&bpcl=40096503&biw=1366&bih=664) on the [current issue of Delhi Gang Rape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2012_Delhi_gang_rape_case), I am posting this question to be aware of the fact if such protests are allowed against the Government in India **as per the constitution?** *Historically*, have these type of protests made good success in India?

Comment: What does " allowed against the Government in India as per the constitution" have to do with "have these type of protests made good success in India?"? These seem like two entirely disjoint questions.

Comment: I think the later one is a sub-question. So merely a link (_if there_) or a short gist would suffice!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wikipedia to the rescue.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_Rights_in_India

> 'Part III - Fundamental Rights' is a charter of rights contained in the Constitution of India. It guarantees civil liberties such that all Indians can lead their lives in peace and harmony as citizens of India. These include individual rights common to most liberal democracies, such as equality before law, freedom of speech and expression, and **peaceful assembly**, ...

...

> **Freedom to assemble peacefully without arms, on which the State can impose reasonable restrictions in the interest of public order and the sovereignty and integrity of India.**

---

The exact wording ([src](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Constitution_of_India/Part_III#Article_19_.7BProtection_of_certain_rights_regarding_freedom_of_speech.2C_etc..7D)) is:

> ```
> Article 19 {Protection of certain rights regarding freedom of speech, etc.}
>   All citizens shall have the right -
>       a) to freedom of speech and expression;
>       b) to assemble peaceably and without arms;
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Under Article 19(1)(b) of The Constitution of India, All citizens shall have the right to assemble peaceably and without arms. But this Fundamental Right is not an absolute right, it is subject to reasonable restrictions in the interest of public order, decency or morality etc.

The Supreme Court of India while giving interpretation of this above Article of Constitution said that-:

The freedom of assembly can be exercised only on public land. Additionally, Restrictions imposed under Article 19(3) would cover restrictions to maintain the public order,including the maintenance of traffic in the area concerned
Source:quora